# import Math namespace in eval()

Tags: javascript

I have function source stored in a string eg.:

```
var source="(function(){return Math.sin(x);})";
```

I want to pass it to `eval()` and calculate it's value later:

```
var f=eval(source);
var v=f();
```

It works well. However, I want to be able to use functions from `Math` without `Math.` prefix. So I would be able to do:

```
var source="(function(){return sin(x);})";
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this? I already use WebGL, so it doesn't have to be compatible with older browsers.

Additional info:

I'm aware that `eval()` is bad. I'm writing function grapher, `source` is function entered by the user that is going to be drawn. That's also why want to get rid of `Math.` prefixes.

I know it's not going to be pretty but I'm not going to write my own parser. Maybe there is some better way?

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing code as strings?  Why not just store function literals in variables so you can avoid the eval?  Is there a reason you don't want the `Math.`?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` at all? Just store `var f = Math.sin`, use an anoymous function if you need more than wrapping a single existing function. You're breaking a butterfly on a wheel. And it's a very ugly, dangerous, slow wheel to boot.

Comment: Question: did you shudder when you typed 'eval'? If not I might suggest finding an alternative solution.  If so, chug ahead, you've passed *my* test for using dangerous things...:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the ancient, slow, ugly `with` keyword to extend the scope:

```
var source="(function(){return sin(x);})";
with (Math) {
    var f=eval(source);
    var v=f();
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: +1, but here are some additional warnings: Can, but shouldn't, just as eval shouldn't be used. It is also bad because it is obscure syntax that lots of people won't recognise causing confusion when they try to maintain the code later.

Comment: @Quentin: I completely agree with you that `"eval".replace("a", "i")`, but since I do not know the background of the program it becomes difficult to propose a better solution. The usage of `with` reminds me of code from over five years ago like `with (document.all) {field.value=1;}`. Ugly (`document.all`) combined with ugly (`with`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)** for this purpose:

```
var source="(function(){return Math.sin(x);})";
with(Math){
    var f = eval(source);
    var v = f();
}
```

See also: **[MDN: `with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)**

Comment: @Banthar If you want to create a kind of calculator, using `eval` would be lazy. When your application uses `eval` for user-input, a potential issue is created.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use `eval()`, maybe you could take the user-entered function and do a few global, case-insensitive replacements:

```
var source = document.getElementById("someInputBox").value;
source = source.replace(/sin/ig,"Math.sin");
source = nsource.replace(/cos/ig,"Math.cos");
source = source.replace(/sqrt/ig,"Math.sqrt");
source = source.replace(/pi/ig,"Math.PI");
source = source.replace(/^/ig,"Math.PI");
source = source.replace(/([a-z]|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*\s*\^\s*([a-z]|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/ig, "Math.pow($1, $2)");
result = eval(source);
```

**IMPORTANT:** The `Math.pow()` replacement won't work for advanced power expressions, such as `5^(5-3^(2*2))`. You'll need to find a more advanced strategy for those. This [website](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=252810) has a solution in `PHP`, which could possibly be converted to `javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

Debates about the safety and compatibility of `eval` aside, one can avoid the performance penalty in this use case via partial evaluation.

If `fstring` is a string containing user input like `"x*cos(x)"`,

```
with (Math) f=eval("(function(x) {return "+fstring+";})");
```

will create a function `f` based on the code in `fstring`. `f` can be applied quickly to a range of values to generate the graphing calculator output. The performance penalty for doing namespace lookups via `with` happens only once, when `f` is created.